# Understanding Dirichlet Process Mixtures

Tags: clustering, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

I have been reading a ton of stuff online and have a question about my understanding of Dirichlet Process Mixtures. First some basics on what I understand:

Dirichlet Distribution:  multivariate generalization of beta distribution

Probability measure: function that assigns subsets to values in [0,1] (a probability)

Dirichlet Process (DP): $P$, a probability measure, is a DP if for every finite disjoint partition $S_1,S_2,\dots S_n$ of space $\omega$, the following is true:

($P(S_1), P(S_2),\dots P(S_n)$)  has Dirichlet Distribution with parameters $\alpha *P_0(S_1), \alpha * P_0(S_2),\dots\alpha * P_0(S_n)$

where $E(P(S_i)) =  P_0$

Ok, I get it so far. Let's move onto Dirichlet Process MIXTURES

Dirichlet Process Mixture =  hierarchical model where

1. $x_i |  \theta_i$ has distribution $f_\theta$
2. $\theta_1, \theta_2\dots\theta_n$  has distribution $P$
3. $P$ is a Dirichlet Process with params $\alpha$ and $P_0$

So let me check to see if I understand these 3 lines correctly

What first line is saying:

a point $x$ comes from a distribution, let's say $f_\theta$ = normal with parameters $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$

What the second and third line are saying is:

My space omega is partitioned into parameter subsets. So let's say our components are normals. So $\theta_1$ = mean 0 with std 1, $\theta_2$ = mean 3 with std 5, ...

So in essence $\omega = \theta_1 \cup \theta_2 \cup \dots$

So $P(\theta_i)$ = probability of us getting the parameter set $i$

Since $P$ is a DP,

$(P(\theta_1), P(\theta_2)\dots)$ has distribution $\mathrm{Dir}(\alpha * P_0(\theta_1), \alpha * P_0(\theta_2)\dots)$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it is better to describe how one would generate data from a Dirichlet process mixture. Each line is understood to be conditional on all lines above it.

1. Sample $P \sim \operatorname{DP}(\alpha P_0)$.
2. Sample $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n \sim P$ independently.
3. Sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ independently such that $X_i \sim f_{\theta_i}$.

That's all there is to it. The only thing different from drawing from a DP versus a DP-mixture is that if you are just drawing data from a DP you stop after step 2 and take the $\theta_i$'s as your data. For a DP mixture, the $\theta_i$'s are not observed but instead represent latent variables.

Comment: But do the thetas in the Dirichlet Process Mixture definition correspond to the S's in the Dirichlet Process definition?

Comment: @ilikecats No, they do not.

Comment: Then what does?

Comment: The reason I thought it would be the thetas is bc of this link: https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/dp_mix.html which says that P0 is a probability measure on the parameter space. That makes me think the thetas are like the S's

Comment: @ilikecats the $S$’s would correspond to subsets of the space of $\theta$’s.

Comment: Ok, so as an example: an element of the space is theta_3 = mean 2 with std=1. Another element of the space could be theta_5 = mean 6 with std=2. A S could be {theta_3, theta_5}.  Correct?

Comment: @ilikecats You wouldn't really think of things like that. Just to make things simpler, lets just think in terms of the mean $\mu$. Then you might have $S_1 = (-\infty, 0]$ and $S_2 = (0, \infty)$ and the prior would be such that $(P(S_1), P(S_2))$ has a Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: Adding to @guy's answer, Dirichlet Process Mixtures are mixtures with respect to Dirichlet Process which means Dirichlet Process is the mixing measure and it is not mixed kernal.